# GAE/Jenkins - cloudbuild service account doesn't have access to projectID

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am running Jenkins locally on Windows 10 and am having a tough time getting it to deploy to Google App Engine (Standard) with a service account. Here is what I've done so far:

- Created a new service account called `jenkins@PROJECT-ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
- Given that service account these permissions:

  - App Engine Deployer
  - App Engine Service Admin
  - Cloud Build Service Account
  - Cloud Build Service Agent ***(not sure if necessary)***
  - Storage Admin
- Downloaded the service account json key, placed it in my Documents folder

Then I used the following commands after my project builds using Node.js:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file %USERPROFILE%\Documents\PROJECT\jenkins-local-sa.json
gcloud config set project PROJECT-ID
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

Then I'm hit with this error:

`(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Failed to create cloud build: cloudbuild service account doesn't have access to projectID "PROJECT-ID".`

I've seen plenty of other errors in my Google search but not this one specifically. Has anyone run across this error?

Comment: The current Cloud SDK version is 303.0.0, can you check your version (`gcloud version`)?. Consider updating to the latest with `gcloud components update`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `service account user` permission in cloud build settings !

Comment: I tried that as well but it didn't work. Hopefully, this question can help someone else. I've gone back to my original solution with Cloud Build instead.